# How can I define if my pc has access to internet with javascript?

Tags: javascript, connection, offline

I am developing an chrome extension application, and I am using this javascript to check if users are connected to any Network.
var statusElem = document.getElementById('status');

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  if (navigator.onLine) {
    // clear the interval
    clearInterval(intervalId);

    // you're online. Redirect to the desired URL
    window.location = "popup.html";
  }
  else {
    statusElem.className = 'offline';
    statusElem.innerHTML = '<span style="color: red">Connect your device to internet</span>';
  }
}, 500);
```

But it doesen't check if the network connection has access to internet, is there anyway to check if we are sending or receiving data from internet?

Answer (score 0):

If it's fine to use a library, you can take a look at this -  http://github.hubspot.com/offline.